# Haskell IO: Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and I try to understand how to do IO correctly.

The following works ok:

```
main = do
  action <- cmdParser
  putStrLn "Username to add to the password manager:"
  username <- getLine
  case action of
    Add -> persist entry
      where
        entry = Entry username "somepassword"
```

Whereas the following results in compilation error:

```
main = do
  action <- cmdParser
  case action of
    Add -> persist entry
      where
        entry = Entry promptUsername "somepassword"

promptUsername = do
  putStrLn "Username to add to the password manager:"
  username <- getLine
```

The error is here:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `[Char]'
Expected type: IO b0
  Actual type: String
In the expression: username
[...]
```

What is going on here? Why the first version works, while the second one does not?

I know that in Stack Overflow there are a few similar questions like this, but none of them seemed to explain this problem to me.

Answer (score 10):

`username` is a `String`, but `promptUsername` is an `IO String`. You need to do something like:

```
username <- promptUsername
let entry = Entry username "somepassword"
persist entry
```

Comment: I'll expand. This is do-notation confusing one. Code  like `do{a;b <- c;d b}` is really a shorthand for `a >>= \_ -> c >>= \b -> d b` . Those who come from imperative world thinks of `<-` here as kind of assignment operator.  It is not. Each line in do-notation translates into anonymous function, and `<-` marks argument of such function. One should be strongly encouraged to read about monads and their practical application to become familiar with them.

Comment: I was actually able to understand the problem and solution without knowledge on monads.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant.

```
main = do
  action <- cmdParser
  case action of
    Add -> do username <- promptUsername
              let entry = Entry username "somepassword"
              persist entry

promptUsername :: IO String
promptUsername = do
  putStrLn "Username to add to the password manager:"
  getLine

-- fake definitions to make things compile

persist :: Entry ->  IO ()
persist = print

cmdParser :: IO Add
cmdParser = fmap (const Add) getLine

data Add = Add deriving Show
data Entry = Entry String String deriving Show
```

The problem is just that `promptUsername` is an *action* not a String. The action 'returns a String', so it has type `IO String`, but it is itself nothing like a String. Since `Entry x y` requires a `String` in the x position, something in the shape of an *action* could no more fit there than a number or boolean could. So in defining your complex action, `main`, you must 'extract' the string that will result from the simpler action `promptUsername` in any case of execution, and give the `String` as the first argument the entry. Then you do the `persist` action on the resulting `Entry`

Comment: Thanks! Your point is also explained in http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output. In general, I find Learn You a Haskell for Great Good! easier to understand than Real World Haskell (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/).